# How to auto-resize tabs to fit a fixed-width container?

Tags: jquery, css, tabs, responsive-design

I appologize if this has been asked before but how would I implement tabs (regular HTML unordered list elements) that resize themselves equally to fit a fixed-width container using CSS and JavaScript?

**Example:** *Google Chrome, Firefox, Sublime Text, etc. *

Comment: search the web for "responsive design"

Comment: You should tag this with "CSS" rather than "javascript" and "jquery"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you know how many 'tabs' you will have, then you can just divide 100 by that number, and set the width to be that percent. ie: `width:20%` for 5 elements.

However...

If you are set on using jquery to dynamically set the width of the element, see the example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/eMLTB/3/

```
<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

jquery

```
var n = $("#nav li").length;
var w = (100/n);
$("#nav li").width(w+'%');
```

css

```
#wrapper { width: 90%; background:#aaa; }
#nav { margin:0; padding:0;}
#nav li { float: left; list-style:none; margin:0;}
#nav li a { display: block; padding:5px; background: #ddd; margin-right:1px; }
```

Comment: This works nicely, but when trying to implement this into existing project, I, for some reason always get the last element on the next row. E.g. 5 tabs, with width: 20%, last element doesn't fit on the same row. If I change one of the `<li>` to 19% instead of 20%, it fits on the same row. I also have padding to the left and right of `<li>`, could that be the reason?

Comment: yes, that is the reason. you would have to subtract the padding from the width. you would also have to set the padding as a percentage.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with just CSS:

```
ul {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

`table-layout: fixed` is the property that is most valuable here. Normally this property has the attribute of `auto` which, when applied to a table, will size the cells according to their content. Fixed will resize the cells and give them each an equal width totalling the width of the container divided by the number of cells. Added bonus: it's faster to compute.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UkcFU/)

Comment: Works fine in Jsfiddle but not in the clean slate blank HTML page and inline css defined in <head>. Tried in latest chrome and firefox browser.

Comment: You might have messed something up. Here is a clean slate HTML page with it working: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/70828364/stackoverflow/15394441/index.htm

Comment: Nevermind, I accidentally typed .ul instead of ul. :p. Coding on the bus is very error-prone.

Comment: What was wrong with my answer? Much cleaner/faster than using JS to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Give the list a display of "table-row", and the list items a display of "table-cell" with a width of 1%.